# Salesforce Org to Salesforce Org synchronization using Heroku Connect Sync

Tags: heroku, data-synchronization, heroku-connect

I would like to set up an Org to Org synchronization.

Is it possible to do Salesforce Org to Salesforce Org Sync using Heroku Connect Sync?

Comment: Do you want to sync two salesforce orgs?

Comment: Yes I want to sync two salesforce orgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but I wouldn't go that route.  Heroku Connect syncs your Salesforce data with a Postgres database on Heroku.  You could sync each org into its own Heroku Postgres DB, but essentially you'd have the same situation -- two separate datasets with nothing to keep them in sync.

You could write some sort of syncing logic on Heroku to copy changes in each database to the other, but that would be tricky!

I'd look at using Salesforce-to-Salesforce instead.  It's an older technology, but it's much simpler -- completely admin-maintainable; no code required.

**Technically, you could sync both orgs into one Postgres DB, but the datasets would still be separate.  There isn't anything that would automatically match up the records.

Comment: Thanks Shane. It was the syncing to a single Postgres DB I was wondering about. Good to know it's not an officially supported approach/use-case.

Comment: Just a clarifying point - you cannot sync into the same database *and* schema. You could do it with different schemas, but as pointed out, that's not helpful.

Comment: apparently one of our clients was sold licenses to Heroku connect by the Sales Engineer for exactly this purpose.  My first thought was the same as this answer... You've basically just introduced another layer of systems and haven't really solved and problems. The challenge is how to map & merge the data, not how to get it in and out of Salesforce.

Seems like a single server handling CDC for both instances would be a more ideal solution.  

Plus Heroku Connect can be extremely expensive!